# How to create a QJsonArray with QJsonObjects using curly brackets syntax in a single line of code?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Let's say I have a **checkable** `QGroupBox` called `groupBoxFlags` (JSON name: `flags`) with four `QCheckBox`es named `checkBoxFlag1` to `checkBoxFlag4` (JSON name: `flag1`, ..., `flag4`) each holding a boolean value for enabling a specific setting in my application. There are multiple cases I want to handle:

- If `groupBoxFlags` is **not** checked - in the JSON document `flags` will become a boolean and will be set to `false`
- `groupBoxFlags` is checked but all checkboxes are **un**checked - same as case above
- `groupBoxFlags` is checked and there is at least one checkbox checked - store an array with all the checkboxes' value instide

The code that handles this is as follows:

```
  QList<bool> flagVals;
  flagVals << ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked()
           << ui->checkBoxFlag2->isChecked()
           << ui->checkBoxFlag3->isChecked()
           << ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked();

  // Counter the number of occurences of TRUE
  int enabledFlags = flagVals.count(true);

  // If flag groupbox is enabled and any of the types of swipe is enabled
  if (ui->groupBoxFlags->isChecked() && enabledFlags > 0) {
    QJsonObject flag1;
    flag1["flag1"] = ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked();
    // ...
    QJsonObject swipeWE;
    flag4["flag4"] = ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked();

    QJsonArray flags = {flag1, ..., flag4};
    stateObject["flags"] = flags;
  }
  else stateObject["flags"] = false;
```

While this works without any issues I saw that Qt supports the curly brackets syntax for creating objects and arrays (examples taken from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html)):

**QJsonObject**

```
QJsonObject object
{
    {"property1", 1},
    {"property2", 2}
};
```

**QJsonArray**

```
QJsonArray array = { 1, 2.2, QString() };
```

I've decided to check it out (definitely saves some writing compared to the code above) however I can't figure out how to do a **one-line** (can be spread across multiple lines for better readability but there has to be only a single semicolon).

The code below is as far as I got:

```
QJsonObject flag1{{"flag1", ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked()}};
// ...
QJsonObject flag4{{"flag4", ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked()}};

QJsonArray flags = {flag1, ..., flag4};
stateObject["flags"] = flags;
```

Is it even possible to get more minimal then this? I actually tried putting all this together like this

```
QJsonArray flags = {
  {{"flag1", ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked()}},
  ...
  {{"flag4", ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked()}}
}; // Error HERE
stateObject["flags"] = flags;
```

but it seems that the `QJsonObject` and `QJsonArray` are mandatory since I get the error

```
/home/user/QtProjects/JsonSaveState/widget.cpp:64: error: conversion from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘QJsonValue’ is ambiguous
     };
     ^
```

and of course going even further

```
stateObject["flags"] = {
  {{"flag1", ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked()}},
  ...
  {{"flag4", ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked()}}
};
```

will not work either. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QJsonObject inside the QJsonArray:

```
QJsonArray flags   {
  QJsonObject{{"flag1", ui->checkBoxFlag1->isChecked()}},
  QJsonObject{{"flag4", ui->checkBoxFlag4->isChecked()}}
};
```

Comment: *facepalm* Yeap, that's it. Also `flags` (that array) can also be added to my `"flags"` object by doing `QJsonArray{ ... }`.